# Remove a text from every tag field of MP3 files in a batch process

Tags: mp3

The website(s) I download most of my songs from spams the shi% out of MP3 tags filling every possible tag fields with its own address.

Is there a tool (for Windows, and preferably free) to search and remove text from all the tag fields of all MP3 files in a batch process?

For eg.

This is a song

> Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up.MP3
>   ID3Tags:
>           Title : Never Gonna Give You Up - [MP3PIRATEJUICE.COM]
>           Artist : Rick Astley - [MP3PIRATEJUICE.COM]
>           Album : Whenever You Need Somebody - [MP3PIRATEJUICE.COM]
>           Genre : Dance-pop - [MP3PIRATEJUICE.COM]

I (only) want to remove " - [MP3PIRATEJUICE.COM]" from all the tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/):

- free
- Windows XP, 2003, Vista, 2008, 7, 8, 8.1
- to remove a given text from all the tag fields of all MP3 files in a batch process:

[image]

[image]

[image]

- You can create groups of actions:

[image]

[image]

[image]

- you can export/import groups of actions:

[image]

```
[#0]
T=4
F=_ALL
1=^\\s+(.*)$
2=$1
3=0

[#1]
T=4
F=_ALL
1=^(.*)\\s+$
2=$1
3=0

[#2]
T=2
F=_ALL
1= )
2=)
3=0|0

[#3]
T=2
F=_ALL
1=( 
2=(
3=0|0

[#4]
T=2
F=_ALL
1=.-.
2= - 
3=0|0
```

- to remove all text from all the tag fields of all MP3 files in a batch process:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there such a tool for Linux?

Comment: @Ejaz https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/83999/903

Answer (score 0):

LOL, maybe MP3PIRATEJUICE isn't the most reputable source of audio ;-)

You can create a custom rule in bliss to do this, and then it will operate on all future music copied into the library too.

To create a custom rule, first create the regex rule. Save this in .bliss/regex-rules:

```
# Rule to remove annoying pirate juice inserts in the tags downloaded
rule removePirateJuice with label "Remove MP3PirateJuice tags" has alternatives  
        REMOVE {
                find /^(.*) - \[MP3PIRATEJUICE.COM\]$/ replace with "$1"
        }
applies to artist, album_name, genre, track_name
```

See: https://gist.github.com/gravelld/80e6ea3cc8ac6ae1b08e15366cb11953

When you restart bliss you'll have this in the settings:

[image: Remove bad characters from fields]

Select all the fields you want trimmed, then "Apply rules". You'll get one-click fixes for each non-compliant album, and you can semi-automate this using "Fix all visible" in the *Inbox* page.