# Remove some given text from every tag field of MP3 files in a batch process on Linux

Tags: linux, mp3

Is there a tool for Linux (and preferably free) to remove some given text from all the tag fields of all MP3 files in a batch process?

Answer (score 1):

One can use `id3info` to view comments and [Sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html) to change them:

- free
- CLI and allow batch process

One would have to write a script around `id3info` and SoX to remove some given text from all the tag fields of all MP3 files. Some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58955612/395857

Comment: Dang, going to have to write a script after all... thanks for the pointer :)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from running a script, there are also apps that run on Linux that you can bulk select and amend the tags via the tag edit. A good example of one I use is:

- [Quod Libet](https://github.com/quodlibet/quodlibet)

There are also other tools that you can use like:

- [Musicbrainz Picard](https://picard.musicbrainz.org/)
- [Beets](https://beets.io/)

Answer (score 1):

You might like exfalso. If all you want to do is clear some tags from a bunch of MP3s, it should do that without problems. It can be kind of slow if there are a lot of them, though. You can add text to tags of lots of MP3s at once, too.